# Eliminate nested empty lists from a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am new to Python and want to ask this question. I have a list that has many types inside it, like int, list, empty list, float, string and I want to create an option to remove any type according to selection, so maybe I want to remove all the int in the list or all the strings. But the tricky part is if I have an input as follows:

```
 [["hello", []], 1, 2.0, [], "hi"]
```

and I want to remove empty list, I expect this to be the output:

```
 [["hello"], 1, 2.0, "hi"]
```

Please help me because as I am struggling to wrap my head around it.

Comment: Have you tried writing any code to solve this problem yourself?

Comment: @Giorgos Myrianthous I want to get my question deleted

Comment: Try to provide an example of what you've tried. Giorgos Myrianthous solution should work. You should mark his answer as correct.

Answer (score 2):

The issue with your existing code, is that it does not take into account *nested* lists.

Here's a recursive solution:

```
def eliminate_empty_lists(_list):
    if isinstance(_list, list):
        return [l for l in map(eliminate_empty_lists, _list) if l != []]

    return _list
```

And the output is identical to the desired:

```
example_list = [["hello", []], 1, 2.0, [], "bonjour"]
print(eliminate_empty_lists(example_list))

>>> [["hello"], 1, 2.0, "bonjour"]
```

Comment: Why is this answer being downvoted? If the OP changes his question every 5 minutes, it is not my fault.

Answer (score 0):

simple recursion approach

```
input = [["hello", []], 1, 2.0, [], "bonjour"]

def removeEmpty(input):
    ans = []
    for i in input:
        if isinstance(i, list):
            if i == []:
                continue
            else:
                ans.append(removeEmpty(i))
        else:
            ans.append(i)
    return ans

print(removeEmpty(input))
```

Comment: isinstance is for check type of i, if it is a list, we need either  skip it as an empty list, or recursion into it to check if there is an inner empty list